# Inequality proof critique

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove an inequality. I think I'm correct but it would be helpful if my proof can be critiqued.

Given two matrices of same dimension $T$ and $P$ with $P \geq 0$ and scalar $\delta>0$, I can prove that for any $0<\epsilon<\delta$,

$T+(\delta-\epsilon)P \leq 0$. Using this, I want to prove that $T+\delta P \leq 0$.

My attempt at proof:

Since $T+(\delta-\epsilon)P \leq 0$ holds for any  $0<\epsilon<\delta$, we get that

$T+(\delta-\epsilon_n)P \leq 0,$ where $\epsilon_n=\frac{\delta}{n}$ for $n \geq 2$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(T+(\delta-\epsilon_n)P\right) \leq 0.$ Consequently,

$T+(\delta-\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \epsilon_n)P \leq 0.$ Since,

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \epsilon_n=0,$ we obtain that

$T+\delta P \leq 0$.

If this is correct, is there some sort of theorem that already proves this or is it alright to state this without proof by just saying that "since this inequality holds for an arbitrarily small $\epsilon>0$, it holds for $\epsilon=0$"?

Thank you.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what you mean by "less than zero". If I pick $T = P = I$ (the 1 x 1 identity matrix) and $\delta = 1/3$, then it's hard to be believe that $ T + (\delta - \epsilon) P \le 0$ for some $\epsilon$ between $0$ and $1/3$. Can you explain?

Comment: Hi John, $T+(\delta-\epsilon)P \leq 0$ holds for particular given $T$ and $P$, not for every $T$ and $P$.

Comment: So your question should be "I have two matrices, $T$ and $P$, fixed, and I'm not going to tell you what they are, but for these two matrices, and some value of $\delta$, I can prove that for all $\epsilon$, ..., and now I have to prove ...". Since I still don't know what you mean by "less than" for matrices, I can't really help...but you might want to phrase your question a bit better for others to be able to do something.

Comment: Yes, I don't have the matrices, that is the assertion. I will reword it. $T+(\delta+\epsilon)P \leq 0$ means that $T+(\delta+\epsilon)P$ is negative semidefinite.